# Tensorflow Dataset Titanic import problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm lost as to how to import Tensorflow 2's built in datasets. Their docs aren't very intuitive and I'm used to working with csvs.

How do I get the 'Titanic' dataset to work with the basic model?
is there a good resource to learn Tensorflow's API for pipelining their datasets?

for the below code I get the error: ValueError: Layer sequential_54 expects 1 inputs, but it received 13 input tensors

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

data = tfds.load("titanic",split='train', as_supervised=True).map(lambda x,y: (x,y)).batch(10)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(13, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=
['accuracy'])

model.fit(data,epochs=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

The import of data seems to be correct, but you are using `categorical_crossentropy` which naturally needs one-hot encoded labels (targets), which can be generated using:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

labels = to_categorical(labels)
```

But for two class (binary) problem, you need to use `binary_crossentropy` and you can still maintain your `dense` layer:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
```

Lastly, you need to add the labels (targets) here to train the network and possibly add batch size

```
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=30, batch_size=80)
```

Comment: this doesn't apply for this tensorflow dataset. thank you for trying.

Comment: my bad. you need to use `binary_crossentropy` instead since it's a two class (binary) problem

Comment: i appreciate it but that doesn't import the dataset properly. like you can't split it ilke that. if you try it you'll see.